# PhpStorm error in Angular template: Unresolved pipe

Tags: angular, phpstorm, webstorm

I have project generated by [Angular CLI](https://cli.angular.io/) ver 7.3.9 (**Angular** ver 7.2.0) and IDE: [PhpStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/) ver 2019.1.2

In template of my component I using [UpperCasePipe](https://angular.io/api/common/UpperCasePipe):

```
<h2>{{ title | uppercase }}</h2>
```

Application works fine. Uppercase works. Letters are big but [PhpStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/) report an error:

***Unresolved pipe uppercase***
*Checks that TypeScript called functions are valid*

preview:

[image]

PS
I have installed *AngularJS plugin*

Comment: why are you using php storm for angular? and if there is plugin, it should be Angular or Angular2, not AngularJS

Comment: i think its your code editor problem.

Comment: AngularJS !== Angular 7. Maybe try to install a more recent plugin, or try using vscode.

Comment: In company we are developing [Laravel](https://laravel.com/) project and all employee got [phpStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/)

Comment: AngularJS plugin description: _Support for Angular and AngularJS projects._ - phpStorm has only this one plugin for Angular

Comment: is `node_modules/@angular/common/src/pipes` folder included in index (check its color in the **Project** tool window)? Also, does the issue persist after caches invalidation (**File | Invalidate caches, Invalidate and restart**)? If yes, please create a support ticket, providing your idea.log

Comment: Make sure you import the pipe in the module

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Please make sure that `node_modules/@angular/common/src/pipes` folder included in index (check its color in the **Project** tool window) - pipes won't be resolved if this directory is excluded

Comment: Yes, that was a problem. I had a `node_modules/` folder as **Excluded**. Thx

Comment: How do you include node_module in index?

Comment: the easiest way to do this is to shut down the IDE, delete the project `.idea` folder and then re-open the project root folder in IDE with **File > Open** - this will re-create the libraries, making sure that all required modules are indexed

Comment: For me right-clicking the node_modules folder and then 'Mark Directory as' > 'Not Excluded' worked

Comment: @MichaelBarfs - Thank you, that did the trick form me 

Comment: Note: If you don't exclude node_modules, they'll start showing up when searching for files. This solution fixes one thing, but breaks another.

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on node_modules -> Mark Directory As -> 'Not Excluded'

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).